# No signature of method: build_#hash#.patchPluginXml() is applicable for argument types: (build_#hash#$_run_closure4) while creating Idea plugin

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

Trying to create brand new plugin project withing IntelliJ and getting:

```
Build file '..MyProject\build.gradle' line: 22

A problem occurred evaluating root project 'MyProject'.
> No signature of method: build_jbffxh3blz36akggm9qv6jfm.patchPluginXml() is applicable for argument types: (build_jbffxh3blz36akggm9qv6jfm$_run_closure4) values: [build_jbffxh3blz36akggm9qv6jfm$_run_closure4@53d43063]

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Why, what does it mean and how to fix?

I am creating new project with

[image]

Java version is 11.0.3

Idea versions are

IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.3 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-211.7628.21, built on June 30, 2021
Licensed to ...

Runtime version: 11.0.11+9-b1341.60 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 10 10.0
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1981M
Cores: 8
Registry: debugger.watches.in.variables=false, scala.erase.compiler.process.jdk.once=false
Non-Bundled Plugins: CMD Support (1.0.5), MatlabSupport (0.8.4), PsiViewer (211.6305.21-EAP-SNAPSHOT), net.seesharpsoft.intellij.plugins.csv (2.17.1), org.antlr.intellij.plugin (1.16), org.jetbrains.plugins.rest (211.6693.44), mobi.hsz.idea.gitignore (4.1.0), com.codename1.plugin.intellij (7.03), CheckStyle-IDEA (5.56.0), YourKit Java Profiler 2017.02-b55 Integration (2017.2.55.0), com.oliverlockwood.plugins.jenkinsfile (1.0), org.jetbrains.idea.grammar (2021.1.2), com.github.masahirosuzuka.PhoneGapIntelliJPlugin (211.6693.44), org.intellij.scala (2021.1.22), MetricsReloaded (1.11.2), com.jetbrains.php (211.7628.25)
Kotlin: 211-1.4.32-release-IJ7628.19

---

Equal sign present:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.0'
}

// See https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin/
intellij {
    version = '2021.1.3'
}
patchPluginXml {
    changeNotes = """
      Add change notes here.<br>
      <em>most HTML tags may be used</em>"""
}
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin/issues/703

Comment: @tim_yates no luck; I already have equal sign; removing of it also doesn't help

Comment: @tim_yates it worked with one of versions; it is weird.